# View or compute request rate for an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to determine the current request rate for an existing AWS bucket to see how near or far I am from running in to the standard request limit of 100 QPS on an S3 bucket. Ideally I'd like to see request rates over time.

CloudWatch doesn't offer any insight in to this information and there does not appear to be any way to retrieve this information for a bucket using the Ruby SDK.

Is there a way to view this information? Do I have to parse my S3 logs and compute it from the log files?

Comment: I am not aware of a *"standard request limit of 100 QPS"* on buckets. What is your source for this?  There are published recommendations related to performance when you sustain over 100 `PUT` or `LIST` requests per second, but a bucket easily handles hundreds of `GET` requests per second and capacity automatically scales up as your request rate grows steadily over time.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html "If your workload in an Amazon S3 bucket routinely exceeds 100 PUT/LIST/DELETE requests per second or more than 300 GET requests per second, follow the guidelines in this topic to ensure the best performance and scalability. " It's not a hard limit, but they will rate limit you if you stay above it for more than a short period of time. Also: I'm doing PUTs.

Comment: They will rate limit you by throwing `503 Slow Down` errors, and, intuitively, it's not because they're counting your requests, but rather because you're overwhelming 1 (or more) of the 1 (or more) partitions in your index -- at whatever rate that might happen to be. I really don't think they are literally counting, and there is indeed no way to interrogate this value (other than log analysis). My approach has always been catch and retry on http errors, with jittery exponential backoff (jittery = pad each wait time with a random number in the range of ±500ms). Follow the guidelines = more RPS.

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no any service in AWS using which you can compute the request rate for AWS S3 bucket. Also there is no any metric that will compute the request rate for you in AWS Cloud Watch. So the only option is to compute the request rate using the AWS S3 Log files.